# Stunnel on Ubuntu 14.04 despite a clean restart

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, stunnel

I am using stunnel4 on Ubuntu 14.04 to forward a connection to a remote connection securely. I restarted the stunnel service and it appears to be running with no issues, but I can not open a connection to 127.0.0.1:8888.

```
$/etc/init.d/stunnel4 restart
Restarting SSL tunnels: [Started: /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf] stunnel.
```

Here is my /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf:

```
cert = /path/to/my/cert.pem
client = yes
[ssl_tunnel]
protocol = proxy
accept = 127.0.0.1:8888
connect = remotehost:443
```

My /var/log/stunnel4/stunnel.log is totally empty. Is there an issue with my conf file?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the process is up - is it listening on port 8888?  Make sure that no other process is already bound on that port before you run stunnel.

**Before running stunnel process:**

```
netstat -an | grep 8888
```

If there is a process running on that port, check which process it is (need to run as sudo).

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8888
```

Once you are sure that no other process is listening on port 8888, run the stunnel process.  Check if the process is up.

```
ps -ef | grep stunnel
&
netstat -an | grep 8888
```

Also make sure that it is binding on 127.0.0.1 (you can always try 0.0.0.0 as well).
Hope it helps.

Comment: As you pointed out, the process is never up even after the restart, and nothing was running on 8888. I've tried 0.0.0.0 as well, is there any other reason it wouldn't be binding?

Comment: is there another process bound on the 8888 port.  What's the output frmo the netstat -an | grep 8888 command.  Is a process already listening there - if so, either shut that process off (use netstat -tulpn to figure out which process it is) or use a different port for stunnel via the stunnel.conf file.

Comment: There is no output from that command and I can bind other processes to 8888.

Comment: Yes I have tried a few. Upon further inspection I see that I have stunnel3 installed as well. I am calling restart on stunnel4 but I wonder if this could cause an issue?